# On the strange calculations calling xfp, Tikz, sqrt, and ^2

Tags: tikz-pgf, mathematics, sqrt, xfp

As we now the square root of (-3)^2+(-4)^2 is the square root of 25 equal to 5.
However we got a strange error calling xfp package and Tikz saying:

> \LaTeX3 error: Invalid operation sqrt(-25)
> Below is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\edef\u{-3};
\edef\v{-4};
\edef\w{\fpeval{sqrt(\fpeval{\u^2}+\fpeval{\v^2})}};

\node   at (0,0) {Ans=\fpeval{\w}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really strange that \u^2 is interpreted as a negative number such as -9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `\u` is not a “variable”, but just a macro and TeX expands it so you get

`\u^2` → `-3^2` → `-9`

Use `(\u)^2`. By the way

```
\edef\w{\fpeval{sqrt((\u)^2+(\v)^2)}}
```

is much more efficient. And you don't need `\fpeval{\w}`, just `\w` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes now makes sence. The key is to use (\u)^2 and not \u^2

Answer (score 5):

Order of operations...exponentiation takes precedence over negation.  Thus, one must explicitly group (via parens) the negatives, lest -3^2 be evaluated as -9.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\u{(-3)};
\def\v{(-4)};
\edef\w{\fpeval{sqrt(\fpeval{\u^2}+\fpeval{\v^2})}};

\node   at (0,0) {Ans=\fpeval{\w}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the problem is the argument of ^2 must be always in parenthesis . So we should not call \u^2 we should call (\u)^2

Comment: @Aria Yes, that is the case.